# $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{2N}}}$ as $\Omega\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, signal-processing

I have a function: $$\rvert H_a(\Omega)\lvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{2N}}}$$

My professor says in the function as $\Omega \rightarrow \infty$, $1+(\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{2N} \rightarrow (\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{2N}$ and hence $\rvert H_a(\Omega)\lvert \rightarrow (\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{-N}$ as $\Omega \rightarrow \infty$. which does not make any sense.

As per my thinking, as $\Omega$ tends to $\infty$, $1+(\frac{\Omega}{\Omega_c})^{2N}$ tends to $\infty$ and hence $\rvert H_a(\Omega)\lvert \rightarrow 0$.

Which is the correct result?and if my professor is right can anyone please help me understand the rationale behind it?

The function$\rvert H_a(\Omega)\lvert$ is the magnitude response of a butterworth filter.

Comment: " $|H_a(\Omega)|\to\left(\Omega/\Omega_c\right)^{-N}$" is not a limit statement, since $\Omega$ still appears. Perhaps your professor was simply describing the *asymptotic behavior* of the function? (Note that, in the limit, $(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{-N}$ is also $0$ (for positive $N$), so you and your professor ultimately agree. :)

Comment: What is $\Omega_c$? Simply a constant?

Comment: With respect to $\Omega$, plot the both functions $1/\sqrt{1+(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{2N}}$ and $(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{-N}$ say for $\Omega_c=1$ and $N=3$, you will se what is happening.

Comment: @robjohn $\Omega_c$ is a constant

Comment: @Blue yes. He did happen to mention asymptotic behavior....but how is $Ha(\Omega) \rightarrow (\Omega/\Omega_c)^ -N$ is there an expression or formula or something......

Comment: @Orpheus: *"How is $Ha(\Omega)=(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{-N}$?"* ... Large $\Omega$ eventually outpaces constant $\Omega_c$, so that $\Omega/\Omega_c$ is itself large. Raising a large number to the $2N$ power makes a LARGE number; adding $1$ to such a thing has virtually-no effect, so you can reasonably ignore it. Doing so, the expression simplifies: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{2N}}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{0+(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{2N}}}=\frac{1}{(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{N}}=(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{-N}$$

Comment: when put like that..it kind of seems obvious...anyways thank you @Blue

Comment: @Blue can you put your comment in the form of an answer so that I can accept it and close the question?...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "$|H_a(\Omega)|\to (\Omega/\Omega_c)^{−N}$" is not a limit statement, since $\Omega$ still appears. Rather, this describes the *asymptotic behavior* of the function.

As for why $|H_a(\Omega)|\to (\Omega/\Omega_c)^{−N}$ holds ... Large $\Omega$ eventually outpaces any constant $\Omega_c$, so that $\Omega/\Omega_c$ is itself large. Raising a large number to the $2N$ power makes a LARGE number. Adding $1$ to such a thing has virtually-no effect, so you can reasonably ignore it. Doing so, the expression simplifies:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{2N}}}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{0+(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{2N}}}=\frac{1}{(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{N}}=(\Omega/\Omega_c)^{−N}$$